# Back up lights do not go off Toyota Tacoma 2002

Tags: toyota, lights

The white back up lights on this truck will not go off. I've taken the bulbs out for a short term fix since the cops pulled me over to tell me it was distracting. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The most likely cause is a defective reverse light switch. It should be located on the side of the transmission. The switch is activated by linkage internal to the transmission. The switch is mounted (screwed into the side) externally. In most cases replacement is pretty straight forward. Unscrew the old, screw in the new. I have also seen rare cases where the sockets were installed in the wrong lens. In these cases the tail (running) lights bulbs shine in the white lens.